# Call Batch file and track progress

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So here is what I'm trying to do.

I have a Powershell script that calls bunch of batch files which installs software. Is there anyway to have a progress bar (GUI would be my choice) to track the status of those batch files that is being called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should this question be flagged since installing software is ambiguous therefore will lead to speculative answers since it is not easy to accurately time software installation?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script.aspx); the article was written by Ed Wilson.

> When using the Write-Progress cmdlet, two parameters are required. The first is the activity parameter. The string supplied for this parameter appears on the first line in the progress dialog. The second required parameter is the status parameter. It appears under the Activity line.

Comment: Do you have a direct link to it?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/29/add-a-progress-bar-to-your-powershell-script.aspx

Comment: Just Google "write-progress powershell".  I use my Google degree for everything.

Comment: I never assume I can find exactly the same thing someone else did by searching with unspecified keywords. If I can, great, but supplying attribution by guesswork is not how I roll.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an example from my PowerShell scripts.  Used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333223/write-progress-for-10-minutes-powershell) for the timer.

The code below has a `FOR` loop to loop over items in a `$variable.Count`

```psh
$time = 7
$percentage = $i / $time
$remaining = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($time - $i)
$message = "{0:p0} complete" -f $percentage, $remaining    
Write-Progress -Activity "Working" -status $message -PercentComplete ($percentage * 100)
```

This example is slightly different and uses a `ForEach` to iterate over items in a collection and update a progress bar.  Below will run and update a progress bar over 60 seconds.

```psh
$time = 60 # seconds
foreach($i in (1..$time)) {
$percentage = $i / $time
$remaining = New-TimeSpan -Seconds ($time - $i)
$message = "{0:p0} complete, remaining time {1}" -f $percentage, $remaining
Write-Progress -Activity "Wait for SCCM scan" -status $message -PercentComplete ($percentage * 100)
Start-Sleep 1
```

--Edit:

Here's code I came up with that successfully launches 5 batch files that each contain `ping 1.1.1.1 -n 2 >NUL` and the `-n` count increases to simulate time elapsed.  *Note the `PercentComplete` option is misbehaving, and my inexperience really shines as I'm unsure it would work in this example.  -edit, forgot to credit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166546/4317867) for getting the `Write-Progress` to work.

```psh
$commands = gc C:\test4\l.txt
$i = 0
foreach ($bat in $commands){
Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c $bat" -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized
$i++
Write-Progress -Activity "Batch File Test" -Status "Completed: $i of $($commands.Count)" -PercentComplete (($i / $commands.Count) * 100)
}#END FOREACH
Write-Host "Batch files finished running!"
```

Comment: Hi User4317867, This works great. But the problem is how do i implement this to track a batch file? I know it's hard to (if not impossible) to time software installation, but is it possible to track the batch file? Say something like installing --> Adobe Reader. Once the batch file completes it writes something like --> installing Flash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to come up with either a time estimate as to how long each step would take or if you have souce access to the installer files, look into adding a timer there.  Then use that in the PowerShell `write-progress` timer bar.  I looked around but did not find any example of a  batch file updating PowerShell's `write-progress` cmdlet.

Comment: Just edited my answer, @Besiktas please try that and let us know how it works.